# Using mathematical induction to prove P(n)

Tags: inequality, proof-verification, induction, factorial

I have the statement
$P(n)$: $2^n<(n+1)!$, for $n \geq 2$;

$P(2)$: $2^2 < 3!$ which is true

I.H P(k): $2^k<(k+1)!$

show that $P(k+1)$: $2^{k+1} <(k+2)!$

Here is my approach:

$2^k<(k+1)!$ multiply both sides by $2$

$2*2^k<2*(k+1)! \Rightarrow 2^{k+1} < 2*(k+1)!$

**since**:
$(k+2)! = (k+2)*(k+1)! \Rightarrow k*(k+1)! + 2(k+1)!$

**hence:** $k*(k+1)! + 2(k+1)! > 2(k+1)! \Rightarrow (k+2)! > 2(k+1)!$

**we can show that:** $2^{k+1} < 2(k+1)! < (k+2)! \Rightarrow 2^{k+1} < (k+2)!$  for $n \geq 2$

I need a feedback about my approach and any correction in case of mistakes.

Comment: Just a heads up, learn to use MathJax to typeset your questions or they will receive a bad response more often than not.

Comment: I will take your advice into consideration. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, I will edit the post.